# Getting Key from Dict as String in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

New to coding here.

I have a dict with strings as keys and arrays of integers as values and I'm trying to get, from a given key, the String of that key. Not the value of the key, but the key itself. Now, I would just put an extra String into the array and call that, but my Xcode seems to have a bug where it really doesn't like having mixed type arrays and it doesn't work.

An example looks like this:

```
var allDict: [String: [Int]] = [:];

allDict.updateValue([1, 2, 3], forKey: "BAGEL"]);
allDict.updateValue([4, 5, 6], forKey: "DONUT"]);
allDict.updateValue([7, 8, 9], forKey: "MACARON"]);
```

I can get the values of each array quite fine with `allDict["DONUT"]![1] //prints 5` for example, but what I want is to get the String of the key.

i.e. I would like to print DONUT using allDict["DONUT"]!

Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have access to the key, since you use that to access the values. It would make no sense at all to retrieve the _key_ using the _key_... Moreover, don't use `updateValue` on a `Dictionary`. Simply use subscripting for accessing values, i.e. `allDict["BAGEL"] = [1,2,3]`. You also shouldn't use semicolons in Swift, this is not Objective-C.

Comment: "... my Xcode seems to have a bug" or maybe, just maybe, you have misunderstood something about dictionaries?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not according to my extensive googling. It's throws an error telling me I have an 'extraneous &' where no '&' exists, and it advices me to replace my 'allDict' with ''. Basically if I have declared an array with AnyObject, then place Int, Int, Int, String in it, and then try to change any values inside the array, it tells me I have too many &'s where no &'s exist, and it won't run. Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: Well without seeing the incorrect code I can't argue against you, it's just when someone blames the tools they are using it is most likely a user error :)

Comment: So, it is possible to have an array of mixed types, but because you declared your dictionary to be of type `[String: [Int]]`, the array can only be composed of Ints. 

Now you could declare your dictionary to be of type `[String: [Any]]` and Xcode wouldn't complain and you could have a dictionary that looks like:

`let mixedDict: [String: [Any]] = ["BAGEL": ["BagelKey", 5, 6, 7, 8]]`

Doing this however, means you either have to cast a value to get the baked in functions for a specific type or you can't use those already built functions on a type of `Any`

Comment: When you write `allDict["DONUT"]` you **do** know the key. It makes no sense to *get* something which is known already. So you can write `print("DONUT")`

Comment: @vadian Okay, but my question is regarding IF and HOW it can be done, not WHY I'd want to do it. My actual use case is not my stated example. But thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @cmyers78 I would do that! Using AnyObject instead of Int I could add the string of the key as a value in the array, but if I use AnyObject I get error `Use of extraneous &` when trying to get/change any values in the array. No matter what.

Comment: @JacobWillén You can't use `Int` with `AnyObject` actually, because it's a value type. As for that error you're getting, based on [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/i-think-i-found-an-xcode-10-beta-error-during-playgrounds/14063/2) it seems to be a poorly-worded error that happens when you try to add the wrong type to a dictionary (such as `Int` to `AnyObject`).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It does work though. I can add both strings and ints using `AnyObject` it seems. Both `Any` and `AnyObject` seem to work while simply printing the values of my dictionary. Both give me that same error when trying to change a value in the array in the dictionary though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you know your keys going in, in this example.

Here are a few ways you might recover your keys in a useful way, though:

Say you have a dictionary

`var dict: [String: Int] = ...`

You could get the array of keys:

```
let keys = dict.keys // keys is of type [String]
```

You can iterate over keys and values:

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    ...
}
```

You can merge dictionaries of and choose values from either dictionary when keys collide:

```
let mergedDict = dict.merge(otherDict) { leftValue, rightValue in 
    return leftValue
}
```

Addressing a version of your original question briefly:

Say you have the value for a certain key:

`let donutValue = dict["DONUT"]`

and somewhere else, where you lo longer have access to the key, you want to recover it from the value somehow.  The best you could do is attempt to find the key by searching through the dictionary with the value you have.

```
var searchResult = dict.first { key, value in
    return value == donutValue
}
```

This assumes the values in your dictionary are Equatable.  Otherwise, you have to write some function or logic to figure out whether or not you've found that value in the dictionary corresponding to `donutValue`.